# What's the difference between "authentication" and "authorization"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I have noticed "Authentication" is used in some mobile apps when I attempt to log in or check my account.

Normally I use "Authorization" in my writing.

Is there a difference between the two? Also, is "Authorization" the same as "Authorisation"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between "log in", "authenticate" and "sign in"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80862/difference-between-log-in-authenticate-and-sign-in)

Comment: @choster Thank you very much for showing me this link,I learned more from the discussion below.But they didn't illustrate the difference between “authentication” and “authorization”.And I think David M reply is great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Authentication* (in this sense) is the confirmation that the person who is giving a command or placing an order is the person they say they are.  In other words, they are making sure that this person is *authentic* or can be identified.

*Authorization* means that you are giving permission to do something.  So, if you *authorize* something, you are saying I allow this based upon my authority.

They are related, but different.

For example:  An app can ask for your *authorization* to make a purchase, then it will attempt *authentication* in the form of a password.

To answer your second question:  Authorisation is an accepted secondary spelling of authorization.  [But, in American English, *authorization* is the preferred spelling.](http://grammarist.com/spelling/authorise-authorize/)

Answer (score 3):

Some idea is is given in the common usage of *authenticate*, in the sense of identifying the subject as being who/what it claims to be.  For example (from the *OED*):

> "To establish the claims of (anything) to a particular character or
>   authorship; to establish the genuineness of; to certify the authorship
>   of."

But in the case you are talking about, these are really specialized uses of the terms, and need to be defined in relation to the technological context in which they are used.

From *AAA and Network Security for Mobile Access*[1]:

> "Authorization is defined as the act of determining whether a
>   particular privilege can be granted to the presenter of a particular
>   credential. [...] The presenter of the credential can be either a
>   device or a user."

The way *authentication* works is broadly the same as the common English usage.

"Authentication consists of two acts: first, the act of providing proof of authenticity for the information that is being delivered or stored, and second, the act of verifying the proof of authenticity for the information that is being received or retrieved."[1]

Another source, [*Network Authentication, Authorization, and Accounting*](http://www.cisco.com/web/about/ac123/ac147/archived_issues/ipj_10-1/101_aaa-part1.html)[2] gives an overview of the terms:

> Authentication asks the question, "Who or what are you?" Authorization
>   asks, "What are you allowed to do?"

and more for *authorization* :

> "At its core, authorization means determining what a client is allowed
>   to do on the network."

(The third piece of AAA, a common technical concept which includes authentication and authorization, is accounting. In the same doc, this is given as "accounting wants to know, 'What did you do?'")

[1] AAA and Network Security for Mobile Access: Radius, Diameter, EAP, PKI and IP Mobility Madjid Nakhjiri, Mahsa Nakhjiri, John Wiley & Sons, Nov 1, 2005

[2] Network Authentication, Authorization, and Accounting: Part One originally from The Internet Protocol Journal - Volume 10, No. 1 (http://www.cisco.com/web/about/ac123/ac147/archived_issues/ipj_10-1/101_aaa-part1.html)